# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type pebble GBitmap

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I'm struggling with a compile error on cloudpebble.

I would like to get the pointer to de pixel data of a GBitmap.

```
static void canvas_update_proc(Layer *layer, GContext *ctx) {
    // Custom drawing happens here!
    GBitmap *fb = graphics_capture_frame_buffer(ctx);

    // Manipulate the image data...
    GRect bounds = layer_get_bounds(layer);

    uint8_t *byte_offset = (uint8_t *)fb->addr;   // <------- error

    int skip_bytes = fb->row_bytes_size - bounds.size.w; // <------- error
```

The compiler returns this error.

```
../src/c/hello_world.c: In function 'canvas_update_proc':
../src/c/hello_world.c:25:38: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../src/c/hello_world.c:27:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I was checking this yt video. https://youtu.be/lYoHh19RNy4?t=2473

How should I solve this?

---

As I was googling, I think it might had something to do with GBitmap isn't known? (at least it's members?)

Answer (score 2):

The structure of GBitmap changed in an SDK update released after that video was published. You can no longer directly access the `addr` member of any GBitmap.

You should now use `gbitmap_get_data_row_info`, and modify that row's info through the data it provides to you.

I'd recommend reading the documentation on [Pebble Developer](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/Graphics/Graphics_Types/#GBitmapDataRowInfo) as well.